# ASP.NET inline coding: variable name is not replaced with value

Tags: asp.net, inline

I have an ASP.NET page .In the page load i set the value of a public variable.and in the inline coding part,I Am loading a CSS which is the folder with the name which is available in the public variable.My HTML markup is as follows

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.cs"  Theme="GridView" Inherits="GUI.MyPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>MyPage</title>
<link href="../Vendors/<%=vendorName%>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
 <body>
<%=vendorName %> <!-- here value is printed correctly -->
 ...
 </body>
```

and in my code behind

```
 public partial class MyPage: MyCommonClass
 {
    public string vendorName = "";
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        vendorName = "ACLL";
     }

 }
```

But when i run the page, the <%=VEndorId%> is not replaced with the value in it .But in the Body,It is printing properly.But in the head it is not coming.I checked the ViewSource and find the source HTML as follows

```
<link href="../Vendors/&lt;%=vendorName%>/Lib/css/tradein.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two options are:

```
<link href="<%= string.Format("../Vendors/{0}/css/style.css", vendorName) %>" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" /> // as Greco stated
```

and

```
<style>
  @import url("../Vendors/<%=vendorName%>/css/style.css");
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the runat="server" tag to the link element.

Comment: Adding runat Not fixed the problem

Comment: <link href="../Vendors/" + <%=vendorName%> + "/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: where did you add runat attribut in the above example ?

Comment: <link href="<%= string.Format("../vendors/{0}/Lib/css/tradein.css",  vendorName) %>"
      type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet"

is the correct code.

No runat=server tag needed my fault! Soz!

Answer (score 0):

Similar question and good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104268/inline-code-in-head-tag-asp-net).

The solution is to move the quotes around the inline code **into** the code

```
<link href=<%="'../Vendors/" + vendorName + "/css/style.css'"%> rel="stylesheet"...
               ^                                           ^
```