# Inline code in head tag - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to do something like this in a head tag, of master page, which has runatserver:

```
 <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<%=Config.ResourcesDomain %>/images/style.css' />
```

This is not working, as it produces this kind of html:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="&lt;%=Config.ResourcesDomain %>/images/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The reason the output is being rendered like so:

```
href="&lt;%=Config.ResourcesDomain %>/images/style.css"
```

Is because ASP.NET is treating the link as an `HtmlLink` control, and rendering the contents of the `href` attribute as a literal.

This is a strange quirk of marking the head section as a server control, where certain elements are treated as server controls (even without being marked explicitly with the `runat="server"` attribute).

Removing the quotations around the href attribute resolves the issue:

```
href=<%= Config.ResourcesDomain %>/images/style.css
```

Doing so stops the link element being treated as a server control, thus executing the code block and rendering the correct URL.

However, the above writes the `href` value out without quotes. Using the following, will add the quotes to the link tag:

```
href=<%= String.Format("'{0}'", Config.ResourcesDomain) %>/images/style.css
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Strangely, if you use double quotes for the `href` attribute, and include double quotes within the code block this also resolves the issue:

```
href="<%= "" + Config.ResourcesDomain %>/images/style.css"
```

---

However, none of the above are particularly elegant solutions, and setting the URL from the code behind is probably the way to go.

Comment: Doing `href="<%# "" + MyString %>"` worked for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: I was going out of my mind! Thanks!!! I needed it to write the correct CSS file based on the user...

Comment: href="css/Login2.min.css?v<%= "" + AppSettingHelper.Version %>"  is working for me

Answer (score 14):

Another solution I've found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5727996/368613 --
just place code inside PlaceHolder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
  ... your code with <%= %> tags ...
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: This is the only working solution I found. Nothing else worked

Comment: Echoing this is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 4):

mark-up

```
<head>
   <asp:Literal ID="litHead" runat="server" />
</head>
```

code-behind:

on page_load

```
litHead.Text = "<link rel='Stylesheet'  type='text/css' href='" + Config.ResourcesDomain + "/images/style.css' />";
```

**Update:**
do this then

```
<head runat="server">
    <%
        Response.Write("<link rel='Stylesheet'  type='text/css' href='" + Config.ResourcesDomain + "/images/style.css' />");
    %>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

Comment: The goal is to set it inline in the head tag, without code behind

Comment: see updated above.
is this some kind of a competition that you need to do it without code behind? As much as possible, avoid using the what we called "Spaghetti Coding" or the inline coding. Those style of coding should be forgotten as those are frequently used back in asp days. ASP.NET beautifully separated the markup and the codes to better practice coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
 <link rel="Stylesheet"  type="text/css" href='<%Response.Write(Config.ResourcesDomain); %>/images/style.css' />
```

It should work

Comment: it still escapes the "<" sign and makes it &lt;%Response.Write(Config.ResourcesDomain); %>/images/style.css

Comment: do you write it in an aspx page ?

Comment: Can you put more all code of master page ,but not the body just the upper part of body

Answer (score 1):

Remove the runat="server" attribute on the opening head tag.
This way the asp.net inline code is correctly rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Or do something like this:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "<%= ResolveUrl("~/content/styles.css") %>";
        @import "<%= ResolveUrl("~/content/print.css") %>" print;
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently data binding is required when using the inline tag "<%# %>".

```
<head id="Head">
    //Stuff with inline code
</head>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load {
    Head.DataBind();
}
```

Regards