# How to set dynamic meta tags in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, meta-tags

I'm trying to add facebook tags to a page. They have to be different for different users, so I try to add them dynamicaly. I have code like this:

```
<meta name="og:title" content="<%= GetSocialTitle() %>"/>
```

But in source page it doesn't uncovers and looks like:

```
<meta name="og:title" content="&lt;%= GetSocialTitle() %>"/>
```

instead of

```
<meta name="og:title" content="some title">
```

I've tried to set meta in code behind

```
HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
tag.Name = "og:title";
tag.Content = GetSocialTitle();
Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
```

But it throws exception "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)". It really contains and I can't replace them. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104268/inline-code-in-head-tag-asp-net

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use code behind remove that og:title meta tag and put runat="server" in head tag.

in markup :

```
<head runat="server">
  ...
</head>
```

and code behind:

```
HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
tag.Name = "og:title";
tag.Content = GetSocialTitle();
Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
```

If you don't want to use code behind, remove runat server from head tag :

```
<head>
  <meta name="og:title" content="<%= GetSocialTitle() %>"/>
  ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another little trick is to use placeholder control around the content.
So in your case, you could...

```
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
             <meta name="og:title" content="<%= GetSocialTitle() %>"/>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and it should translate correctly.

HTH

Dave