# Why do I need to include a blank string in front of my function name in inline ASP for it to get evaluated?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to set my css theme based on a `Request.QueryString` variable. My code for selecting which Css theme to use is in a Function, however the function is getting rendered as output instead of getting evaluated and the output being rendered.

Using `<%= GetCssTheme() %>` makes it render as

```
<link href="Content/<%= GetCssTheme() %>.css" rel="Stylesheet">
```

however if I use `<%= "" + GetCssTheme() %>` it gets correctly rendered as

```
<link href="Content/ThemeA.css" rel="Stylesheet">
```

Here's a small sample that illustrates the problem:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" %>

<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
    Public Function GetCssTheme() As String
        Select Case Request.QueryString("SomeValue")
            Case 2
                Return "ThemeB"
            Case 3
                Return "ThemeC"
            Case Else
                Return "ThemeA"
        End Select
    End Function
</script>


<html>
<head runat="server">
    <link href="Content/<%= GetCssTheme() %>.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    Test
</body>
</html>
```

Why do I need to specify a blank string in front of my function name for it to work?

I have tried various other methods too:

- Using single quotes instead of double quotes
- Using`<%= GetCssTheme().ToString() %>`
- Using `<% Response.Write(GetCssTheme()) %>`
- Using

```
<%
    Dim s as String
    s = GetCssTheme()
    Response.Write(s)
%>
```

All of these incorrectly render the ASP.Net code itself instead of evaluating it and outputting the result.

The only thing I tried that does actually work is using in-line code instead of calling the function, or add a blank string to the function call.

Comment: Have you tried something like this...Response.Write("--> " & GetCssTheme() & " <---").  That will at least tell you if the Response.Write is rendering or not.

Comment: @ctorx That actually works.... I'll update my question with that result. But why? `Response.Write("" + GetCssTheme())` works but `Response.Write(GetCssTheme())` does not.

Comment: Did you get the arrows and the value from the function?

Comment: MY guess is some artifact elsewhere on your page like a missing closing tag or quote, but I've seen this weird behavior happen for no apparent reason before.

Comment: @ctorx I can't stand things happening for "no apparent reason". There must be a reason somewhere.... I don't see any closing tags missing in my html

Comment: Can you post more of your Web Form?  It might be helpful in identifying the root cause.

Comment: @ctorx That's my entire aspx file. I made a new aspx file, copied the relevant bits of code, and I trimmed it down as small as I could make it to eliminate any possibilities that it could be something else in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of the runat="server" on your head tag.  If you take it away the code will work just fine.  This seems to be an old issue...

This URL shows the problem much like our dialog has been on this question, but has no cause.

http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2007/11/14/code-render-blocks-not-always-work-inside-server-controls.aspx

So, if you don't need the runat="server" on your head tag, that will fix the issues...alternatively, if you do, you can always place the LINK tag at the start of the body which is not ideal.

I'll continue to look, but I think this is either a side effect of other functionality or it is a bug in ASP.NET.

**UPDATE:**

I found this other SO question which specifies the cause. - 
[Inline code in head tag - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104268/inline-code-in-head-tag-asp-net)

Comment: I've tried both single quotes and double quotes, and both exhibit the same behavior. I've also tried to use `GetCssTheme().ToString()` in case it was having trouble identifying the return value as a String, but that also doesn't work. I guess I can use a blank string before the function call, but I'm really curious why I need to do this in the first place

Comment: I've updated my question to focus more on the "why" instead of just looking for a quick hack to fix it. Perhaps you could update your answer as well?

Comment: For some reason the compiler isn't executing the code...the string literal ("") is forcing that to happen.  Have you tried <%=GetCssTheme()%> without the space after the equals sign?

Comment: Just tried it now with no change. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and simply created a new ASP.NET Empty Web Application project.

Comment: Hrrmmmm your code actually works for me. The only difference I can see is the `runat="server"` in my `<head>` tag that was part of the default new WebForm template. Yours doesn't have that, and sure enough when I removed that it runs just fine. I'm so confused... and I'm again reminded of why I hate working with websites and Vb.Net >.<

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening is the contents within the HREF is a string and the GetCssTheme() is acting like a variable. Think of it as when you do it in code:

```
Dim s as String = "Some text " & Variable & " more text"
```