# server side variable cannot be resolved in link element

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have been scratching my head and trying to figure this out. I have a site.master page

and I am just trying to do a simple thing. I am including a link element in the header

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<%=CannoicalURL%>" />
```

the above however, always resolves to `Views/CMSTemplates/%3C%25=%20CannoicalURL%20%25%3E` 
So in other words, the value of CannoicalURL isn't even rendered

CannoicalURL is a string variable i set in the code behind, i checked the value in debugger and it is fine...

Further more, I even created a dummie javascript below

```
<script>

    var a = <%=CannoicalURL%>;
</script>
```

And this works perfectly.

Can somebody explain why it doesnt quite work with  element? Any solutions/suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: It's not because you spelled "Canonical" wrong, is it?  Could you post your variable declaration and its context please?

Comment: @pseudocoder I don't think, since they used the same expression elsewhere (in the script tag) and it worked fine

Comment: It's not the quotes doing it is it? Try passing the quotes in the variable rather than including them in the string in the head.

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104268/inline-code-in-head-tag-asp-net

Answer (score -1):

is your head tag marked with `runat="server"`?  if so, tags inside that control cannot be modified inline since ASP.NET is managing the control.

if this is the case, remove the `runat="server"` from your `<head>` tag

Comment: O.o Try running a control anywhere in ASP.net from code behind that doesn't have run at server attached...

Comment: @RickCalder a <head> tag is not an asp.net control.  that is an html tag.  maybe you should try removing the runat=server attribute from the head tag yourself and see that it is not required.

Comment: Read that wrong somehow, wasn't me that downvoted you just so you're aware.

Comment: yes, I do have <head runat="server">, so are you saying i should remove runat="server" from the <head> element?

Comment: Yes.  Please try that.  In theory this should help.