# variable name is not replaced with value inside head tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

My asp.net site has a navigation that uses an .active css tag to change the color of the navigation color on active pages.

This is in my site.master header

```
.active
{
 background-color: #c62020; 
 border-right: 1px solid;
 margin-left: -1px;
}

</style>
```

This works great as is. But now I want it to change the background color depending on a variable, I have the code to do it in the Site.Master.cs.

I understand that I cant use <%= %> inside the header. Whats the best way to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: you can add server tags to the head, just be careful how, as they render differently. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104268/inline-code-in-head-tag-asp-net

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and got 'WebApp.SiteMaster.hextag' is inaccessible due to its protection level. Even though I put string hextag = "#c62020" in the public class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage. I will keep playing with it and see why I get that error.

Comment: ViewData/ViewBag or a custom rendering section perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not putting your css class outside of head and put it in the body and then you can use server tags there `<% %>`

The another way is through jQuery or javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.active').css("background-color","<%=serverVariable%>");
});
```

Comment: In the Site.Master.CS file how do I set the serverVariable? I must be doing something wrong, I jsut want my serverVariable = "#c62020".

Comment: I got it working forgot to make the servervariable public. If I put the css in the first link of the <body> it doesn't render.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know this is best way or not. I am also beginner. But I have done this as follow..
call JavaScript function from server side in your .cs file like

```
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "keyforfun",fun_setHeadcolor(your_variable), true);
```

Then in your site.master page add javaScript function called "fun_setHeadcolor" like

```
function fun_setHeadcolor(var1)
{ 
  //do stuff here to change background color
  //for example   $('.active').css("background-color",var1);
}
```