# .aspx HTML HEAD adding UnixTimestamp to stylesheet does not work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, caching, browser-cache

I would like to add an parameter to my css and js files to not allow the browser cache specific files.

I tried two versions in my index.aspx and my c# code but nothing works.

The first try was to add DateTime.Now.Ticks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="_index" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Index Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/sweetalert2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks %>">
```

But the relevent Line shows up exactly like this when rendered so there isn't the Ticks after style.css? and instead the aspx code.

Another version was to write a UnixTimeStamp function which returns my Unix Time Stamp:

```
public Int32 UnixTimeStampUTC()
    {
        Int32 unixTimeStamp;
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime zuluTime = currentTime.ToUniversalTime();
        DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        unixTimeStamp = (Int32)(zuluTime.Subtract(unixEpoch)).TotalSeconds;
        return unixTimeStamp;
    }
```

The I included it like the following but the result was the same:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="_index" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Index Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap-
datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/sweetalert2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?<%= UnixTimeStampUTC() %>">
```

This again renders to :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Index Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap-
datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/sweetalert2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?<%= UnixTimeStampUTC() %>">
```

In the rest of my .aspx i also using this technique to show an NTLM User and ther it works.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I now have got a Workaroud for a solution:
I added a function that returns the complete link 
    public String noCache(String url){
    return '"' + url + "?ver=" + UnixTimeStampUTC() + '"';
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline code in head tag - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104268/inline-code-in-head-tag-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys i found a solution,
maybe not the best but it works.

In .aspx.cs i wrote a function to generate a cache url. This function also uses my UnixTimeStampUTC() function from above:

```
public String noCache(String url){
  return '"' + url + "?ver=" + UnixTimeStampUTC() + '"';
}
```

I'm then using this function in my .aspx like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=<%= noCache("css/style.css") %>>
```

Maybe this helps someone searching fo a simmilar solution.